# Maven - Password Encryption

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven and trying to understand the password encrytion.

I have installed maven and created .m2 folder and inside settings.xml and settings-security.xml.In the settings I have proxies where I give the server password. And in the settings-security I give the master password.

My question: what is this master password and server password for? I understand from the document that the password are encryted and saved as master password. My doubt is how does this master password and server password works in a simple flow.
Can these passwords be a random one or should it be a login password to the server.

Thank you.

Comment: may i know the server you are using ?

Comment: Its the Hadoop nodes I am using.

Comment: I would like to understand how the master and server password works.